# UE5 Player Pawn Not Spawning Despite Game Mode & Default Player Pawn Override

Tags: unreal-engine5

I have a large level set up, am overriding default Game Mode with a custom one and within the Game Mode am overriding the Default Pawn Class to a custom one I've made. I also have the same configuration for GM & Pawn in project settings. There are no other pawns or cameras on the map to be possessed.

Despite this a default static Camera Actor gets spawned and possessed at world origin while my custom Pawn never spawns when I start playing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my custom pawn does spawn as expected when it's below ~ 1,000,000 units away from world origin, anything beyond that and the static Camera Actor gets spawned instead. Had to go to the World Settings for the level and check "Enable Large Worlds". Now everything works as expected.